# either with be and ing

Tags: conjunctions, negation

I have this statement:

> The document will not be indexed nor retrieved.

I know it is not correct and I must use `either`. So, my question is:

What is the correct sentence:

> The document will not either be indexed nor retrieved

Or:

> The document will not either being indexed nor retrieved

I have feeling that the second one is correct while I knew that after `will` we have to use the zero form, which is `be` not `being`

any reference to learn more about that grammar is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct sentence to use would be:

> The document will neither be indexed nor retrieved.

You always use *either* with *or* and *neither* with *nor*, and you never use *either* with *nor* and *neither* with *or*. Here are two examples:

> Choose **either** the red one **or** the blue one.
>
> You are **neither** an astronaut **nor** a scientist.